# Android SDK virtual device fail?

Tags: android

I using Eclipse Helios and JDK6 ,
The Android SDK virtual device make a problem follow the step.

1. The device cannot shut down,it stop at

> 09-03 03:59:02.986:
>   INFO/ShutdownThread(72): Performing
>   low-level shutdown...

2. If i force close the device, i cannot start up again, it make emulator.exe
   crash.
3. It have only one way to make the device can startup again, 
   before launch the device , check "wipe use data".

So any body experience this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment Google does not recommend using Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) with the Android Developer Tools. I personally had a lot of problems and reverted back to 3.5.

For your device problem I'd probably just create a new virtual device with 2GB of SD card memory.

Comment: hmm, I create the virtual device with 2048MB,1024MB SD Card , and still not work.
Maybe i downgrade to eclipse 3.5...